# Proof of equality - possibly previously answered

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I am looking for a proof of the following inequality
>   Let a be a positive real number. Prove that for every natural number n
>   $$(1+a)^n\ge 1+na.$$

Can you help?

Comment: \leq produces $\leq$ and \geq produces $\geq$

Comment: This is called the Bernoulli's inequality:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it by induction :

Base case :

$$1+a \geq 1+a$$

Induction step :

$$(1+a)^{n+1} = (1+a)(1+a)^n \geq (1+a)(1+na) = 1+a+na+na^2 \geq 1+(n+1)a$$

Answer (score 0):

Try the binomial theorem.

Then $(1+a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k$. Taking the first two terms gives
the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It's called *Bernoulli's inequality*, and you even have more: if $a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n$ are numbers all $>-1$, with the same sign, then:
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\dotsm(1+a_n)\ge 1+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n.$$
Proof by a simple induction:
\begin{align*}
(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\dotsm(1+a_n)&(1+a_{n+1})\ge (1+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)(1+a_{n+1})\\
&=1+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n+a_{n+1}+ a_{n+1}(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)\\
& \ge=1+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n+a_{n+1}
\end{align*}
since $\,a_{n+1}(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)\ge 0\,$ (all numbers have the same sign).

*Addendum.* In the case $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=a$, you have a stronger result: if $a>-1$, then:
$$(1+a)^n\ge 1+na+\frac{n(n-1)}2 a^2.$$

Comment: This too has a mechanical telescopic proof as in my answer.

Comment: Your proof can't work if $-1<a<0$, or do I miss something?

Comment: The OP has $\, a > 0.\ $

Comment: Yes, but the interesting case, in my opinion is it can also be true for negative numbers (as an exercise that is not so trivial, even with the binomial formula).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \, f_n = (1+a)^n/(1+na)\,$ is a *telescoping* product of factors $\,\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n} \ge 1,\,$ so it is $\,\ge 1,\,$ e.g.

$$\dfrac{(1+a)^4}{1+4a} =\, \dfrac{(1+a)(1+a)}{\qquad\quad\color{#c00}{ 1+2a}}\ \dfrac{(\color{#c00}{1+2a})(1+a)}{\qquad\quad\ \ \color{#0a0}{1+3a}}\ \dfrac{(\color{#0a0}{1+3a})(1+a)}{\qquad\quad\ \ 1+4a}\qquad $$

Each factor is $> 1$ by $\ \underbrace{(1 + na)(1 + a)}_{\large\rm numerator}-\,\underbrace{(1+(n\!+\!1)a)}_{\large\rm denominator} =\, na^2 \ge\, 0 $

**Remark** $\ $ Equivalently $\, f_n\,$ is *increasing* $f_{n+1}\ge f_n\,$ so $\ f_n\ge f_1 = 1\,$  by induction.